# I dynamically created a div using Javascript/DOM. How do I get the div to appear on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to make a web page where some of the elements are dynamically created. I wrote the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Here's some example text</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var jselem = document.createElement ("div");
        jselem.innerHTML = '<p>and here\'s some more</p>';
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, the JS section does not seem to be doing anything, the text `and here's some more` is not printed.

Can anyone shed some light on why it is not working? Any help is appreciated.

(Please do not suggest using `document.write()` or similar.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `document.body.appendChild()` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/C3DvL/show/))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jselem = document.createElement("div");
    jselem.innerHTML = '<p>and here\'s some more</p>';
    document.body.appendChild(jselem);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You created the element, but didn't insert it into the document yet. That doesn't happen automatically -- until you do so, it's just a div floating around in memory.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement